# Printing in Javascript whilst using <%# %>

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, printing

I need to print a `DataViewGrid` from a website made in ASP.NET and have am using JavaScript to do it as it seems much easier that achieving it is C#. Below is the code that I am using to try and print the document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doPrint() {
    var prtContent = document.getElementById('<%# dgvInvoices.ClientID %>');
    prtContent.border = 0;
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=100,top=100,width=1000,height=1000,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1');
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.outerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
}
```

I had to change line 3 from `('<%= dgvInvoices.ClientID %>');` because it was giving me a control error, and now I believe this is stopping my document from printing. Does anyone have any work around or fixes for this? Or an easy way to print in C#?

The original error was:

> *The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).*

Comment: "(...) it was giving me a control error". Which error?

Comment: What happens if you change `<%# .... %>` to `<%=(...)%>` ?

Comment: The error was The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). and changing it to <%=(..)%> did not fix the original error

Comment: i am not sure what is the problem  , but i have tried this with another workaround . i have rendered javascript using code behind ( you can use literal control of this ) or simply render it.  

or keep a hidden textbox and using C# server side code populate the client id in that hidden text box and then use it from javascript code.

Comment: @user1524116 Have you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Ajax and have a ScriptManager in your page or master page, you could do:

```
var prtContent = $get('<%= this.dgvInvoices.ClientID %>');
```

Also, if you are using the .Net framework version 4 or above, you can set the property `ClientIDMode="Static"` in the control, so the ClientID will be rendered as declared and you'll be able to use the `document.getElementById` javascript function passing the declared ID as parameter.